# Compare formulas, which is most efficient

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is there a way to test speed/efficiency of formulas in Excel ?

This can be done in SQL Server by showing the actual excecution plan, is there anything that Excel can do similar.

For example, the below queries will all give me the same result,

```
{=SUM(SUMIF(A:A,D1:D3,B:B))}

=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1:A25,D1:D3,0))*B1:B25)

=SUMIF(A1:A25,D2,B1:B25)+SUMIF(A1:A25,D3,B1:B25)+SUMIF(A1:A25,D1,B1:B25)
```

If I was to use these formulas over 1000s of rows my worksheet will take longer and longer to calculate.

How can I determine which is the most efficient to use ?

The problem doesn't just relate to these examples, is there a way in general of finding out the execution/performance ?

Comment: The first and the third will be the same.  The second will iterate 25 times instead of 3  of the other two.

Comment: Hi @ScottCraner how do you work that out ?

Comment: Look at what is iterating in the first the part that iterates is not the full column references it is the `D1:D3` so 3, it does 3 SUMIF.  The next, the part that iterates is `A1:A25` and `B1:B25` so actually it iterates 50 times.  In this case the SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF()) will be quicker.  As long as the criteria range is less than the lookup range it will continue to be.

Comment: @ScottCraner, explaining that would make a good answer.

Comment: @PeterH,, this should be the Formula to work with `{=SUMPRODUCT(MATCH(D1:D3,A1:A25,0))*(B1:B5)}`, ISNUMBER is not required.  You can use INDEX instead of ISNUMBER even !!

Comment: Hi @RajeshS thanks for the comment, so the main part of the question is **HOW** do you know which is the most efficient to use ? not which one.

Comment: @PeterH,, principally SUMPRODUCT is an Array which normally takes much time then Non-array Formula, this is the prime reason but to determine is, the best method should,, test both and I've use VBA code to determine this,, instead of manual work around or around Assumption or Perceptions (since I'm a techie) ,, try the code,, you find which took less time !!

Comment: If you have some knowledge of the internal workings of Excel, you can often guess what will be faster.  But that is dangerous.  Some processes take longer than others.  For example, some functions use approximate calculations, some do iterative calculations until an error threshold is reached, etc.  The best way to get a reliable answer is to actually time it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*In few Manuals I found that **SUMIF** or **SUMIFS** is faster than **SUMPRODUCT**, therefore I've deiced to test which one is faster and I've used VBA code shown below, counts the Elapsed time taken by Both Formulas.*

```
Sub CalculateRunTime()

 Dim StartTime As Double
 Dim SecondsElapsed As Double


 StartTime = Timer

'Range("E28").FormulaArray = "=SUMPRODUCT(MATCH(B25:B27,A25:A50,0))*(C25:C50)"

Range("F28").Formula = "=SUMIF(A25:A50,B25,C25:C50)+SUMIF(A25:A50,B26,C25:C50)+SUMIF(A25:A50,B27,C25:C50)"

 SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)


  MsgBox "This code ran successfully in " & SecondsElapsed & " seconds", vbInformation

End Sub
```

**Results:**

*Time taken by SUMPRODUCT:*

[image]

*Time taken by SUMIF:*

[image]

**N.B.**

- I found **SUMIF** has taken less time.**
- Elapsed time may vary during some test, 
  since depends on speed on **CPU** also.
- You can use this code if want to get 
  elapsed time in minutes, if using huge 
  data range.

  ```
  MinutesElapsed = Format((Timer - StartTime) / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")


  MsgBox "This code ran successfully in " & 
  _ MinutesElapsed & " minutes", VbInformation
  ```

Comment: would be great if you could share results too, so we could better understand the differences.

Comment: @MátéJuhász,, edited my post and included the results.

Comment: there are three options of the test, but you've only two results why?

Comment: @MátéJuhász, since `SUM(SUMIF,,,,)` and the `SUMIF` are almost similar and I've compared with `SUMPRODUCT`, using the code as many Formula can be tested !!

Comment: First sumif is an array formula, and sumproduct is not an array formula. You seem just mixed them in your code.

Comment: **Cont.,,** the `SUMPRODUCT` used by @PeterH must be an Array ,, *the non array form doesn't works* I've tetsted both in my Sheet and then used with code,,, and produces results.

Comment: The whole purpose of running this is to measure the actual time rather than speculate on what would be faster and why.  That fact that this answer shows only two of the examples in the question is irrelevant.  It only needs to demonstrate the technique.  Besides, the question specifically states that what is desired is a method for determining this, not the results for these specific examples.  It accomplishes what the alternative in the question describes, replicating the formula thousands of times, with a small amount of reusable code that produces automated results. +1

Comment: @fixer1234, thanks for valuable feedback, my experience says `TIME` is the best parameter to determine the efficiency of the `CODE/FUNCTIONs`, and which could be demonstrated also, otherwise `Array & Non Array` both performs the job, and for smaller data set no one minds,, which is good or bad, getting solution is the ultimate goal. And if we pick `HOW `then once again only the illustration comes into picture that which part doing what & how accessing data, so I found calculate the TIME is as innovating idea ☺

Comment: Glad to help you @PeterH ,, keep asking ☺